# Sorting element to the top of an array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to apply a custom sorting comparator to a gulp stream (so I don't have the ability to customize the array). I'm trying to sort everything alphabetically except for a single shared file, which should be sorted to the very top.

Running a simple [jsbin test](http://jsbin.com/kababoyale/edit?js,console) though, I'm seeing the same problem - the file I need at the top isn't sorting correctly.

```
var files = [
  'app/modules/t.css',
  'app/shared/dialogs/c.css',
  'app/shared/directives/m.css',
  'app/shared/scss/app.css',
  'app/shared/modals/a.css',
  'app/shared/modals/b.css'
];

files.sort(function(file1, file2) {
  var sort = 0;

  if (file1.indexOf('shared/scss') > -1) {
     sort = -1;
  } else {
     sort = file1.localeCompare(file2);
  }

  return sort;
});
```

The resulting output is incorrect, `app/shared/scss/app.css` has only moved up twice.

```
"app/modules/t.css"
"app/shared/dialogs/c.css"
"app/shared/directives/m.css"
"app/shared/scss/app.css"
"app/shared/modals/a.css"
"app/shared/modals/b.css"
```

Here's what I'm expecting:

```
"app/shared/scss/app.css"
"app/modules/t.css"
"app/shared/dialogs/c.css"
"app/shared/directives/m.css"
"app/shared/modals/a.css"
"app/shared/modals/b.css"
```

Comment: Your comparison is broken; what if `file2` has that path?

Comment: Ah I noticed this just now too... doh! That's the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `file1` isn't the only variable that could contain `app/shared/scss/app.css`, there's also `file2`. In your sort function, you're only checking `file1`.

So, this sort function should behave the way you intended it to:

```
files.sort((file1, file2) => {
    let sort = 0, substring = "shared/scss";
    if (file1.includes(substring)) {
        sort = -1;
    }
    else if (file2.includes(substring)) {
        sort = 1;
    }
    else {
        sort = file1.localeCompare(file2);
    }
    return sort;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `file1` contains `shared/scss`, but you're not checking if `file2` contains it. Add another condition, `file2.indexOf('shared/scss') > -1`, and if it's true, set `sort` to `1` to make `file2` appear on the top.

```
var files = [
  'app/modules/t.css',
  'app/shared/dialogs/c.css',
  'app/shared/directives/m.css',
  'app/shared/scss/app.css',
  'app/shared/modals/a.css',
  'app/shared/modals/b.css'
];

files.sort(function(file1, file2) {
  var sort = 0;
  if (file1.indexOf('shared/scss') > -1) {
     sort = -1;
  } else if (file2.indexOf('shared/scss') > -1) {
     sort = 1;
  } else {
     sort = file1.localeCompare(file2);
  }

  return sort;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal which moves `'shared/scss'` to top.

```js
var files = ['app/modules/t.css', 'app/shared/dialogs/c.css', 'app/shared/directives/m.css', 'app/shared/scss/app.css', 'app/shared/modals/a.css', 'app/shared/modals/b.css'];

files.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = +!a.match(/shared\/scss/),
        bb = +!b.match(/shared\/scss/);
    return aa - bb || a.localeCompare(b);
});
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(files, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```